# Can someone explain the cancellation in this Induction proof? (Harmonic Sequence)

Tags: induction, harmonic-numbers

I'm in computer science, but unfortunately my mathematics skills leave a lot to be desired. Anyhow, I pulled up this sheet to help me, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how it works for steps (described in the document after the proof) 4-6.

In particular, could someone please explain how 2^n accounts for these aspects of the sum, and then, why we multiply by 1/2^(n+1)?

The paper I pulled up doesn't do a great job of explaining that.

(As a side note: Any suggestions on how to get better at this stuff? I really seem to be the village idiot....)

http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~hsharp/math2420/harmonic.pdf

I sincerely appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

They are using the fact that $\frac{1}{2^n+k} \geq \frac{1}{2^n+2^n} = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ for any $k\leq 2^n$ to move from (4) to (5),(notice there are $2^n$ of such terms, that's why you see the  $2^n \times \frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$

then they simply cancelled $2^n$ on both numerator and denominator to get from (5) to (6)

Comment: So, do they assume equality of 1/[(2^n)+k] and 1/2^(n+1) to arrive at this conclusion?

Sorry, I'm still a bit foggy on how exactly that step means something. Please bear with me, I'm really bad at this :(

Comment: so this inequality here $\frac{1}{2^n+k} \geq \frac{1}{2^n+2^n}$  for $k\leq 2^n$is not something they have to assume, it is just true. Think about it, you have a bigger denominator on the right since $k\leq 2^n$, that makes the left term bigger than the right term

Comment: does what I wrote make sense?

Comment: I think I may have assumed too much knowledge on the previous steps :(

Could you give me a quick rundown of what's going on? Maybe if I understand how that EQ is arrived at I'll get it better. Perhaps it's a property of the harmonic sum I don't know?

They always assume you know this stuff, and nobody tells you :(

Thank you very much for your continued assistance, by the way.